Shapefile of Cairo's wards (Kism)
Is there a website where I can download Cairo's wards (Kisms) as a shapefile? Attached is an image of what I am looking for.

Effat & Elshobaki, 2015

These wards are a "second-level administrative division". For Egypt, you can download their boundaries in shapefile format at this address, from the page "Egypt - Subnational Administrative Boundaries" on the Humanitarian Data Exchange (HDX) website. Note that sometimes the anglicized name of the wards may have a somehow different spelling between the map in your question and the data in the HDX shapefile (for example, "El Basatein" vs. "Basatin").
The shapefile includes second-level administrative boundaries for all Egypt. The specific wards you're looking for are included in it. It means you'll have to load the shapefile in some GIS software (QGis, etc.), and then extract your wards of interest from it.
Here's a very quick-and-dirty view of what I can get in QGis with the HDX data (keeping the neighboring wards in this example):

In case you don't know how to extract this subset of wards from the shapefile, you can refer to the documentation of the software you're using (for instance, if you're using QGis, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360364/extracting-subset-of-polygons-from-shapefile). Subset extraction is a common procedure when working with map data, so it's worth learning how to do it, if you plan to work with maps in the future.
